# SSL integration with Devise How-To, Not Authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https, devise

I am using [SSL Requiremen](http://rubygems.org/gems/bartt-ssl_requirement)t to achieve the proper rediects with [Devise](http://rubygems.org/gems/devise). I am using custom devise controllers so I am able to drop in the ssl_required in them.

## Gemfile

```
gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', '1.2.7', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
```

## application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  include ::SslRequirement
```

I also customized the hostname for SSLRequirement

## production.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
    SslRequirement.ssl_host = 'secure.website.com'
end
```

Setting up Custom Devise Controllers is as simple as making a new controller file and having the appropriate naming: (e.g. Session Controller). Be sure to generate the views and move them into the appropriate folder so your custom controller can use them.

## session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
ssl_exceptions

def new
   super
end

...
```

All this is working for met yet once I enable ssl_required (or ssl_exceptions), Devise is no longer able to authenticate. It redirects me to index or keeps me on the login page.

I made sure to go into session_store.rb and update my cookie_store to include

## session_store.rb

```
App::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_session', :httponly => true, :secure => true, :domain => '.website.com'
```

for me, adding `:domain => :all` was not solving the problem either

Went into my devise.rb file and included:

## devise.rb

`config.cookie_options = { :secure => true` }
still no success... even wrote all custom routes skipping over Devise defaults so they would include the https protocol and the secure subdomain host, and skip default devise routes to get rid of duplicate paths... I'm running out of options at this point:

## routes.rb

```
constraints :protocol => "https", :host => "secure.website.com" do
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations', :passwords => 'passwords', :confirmations => 'confirmations', :unlocks => 'unlocks' }, :skip => [:sessions, :passwords, :registrations]
devise_scope :user do

  #sessions
  get "/users/sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => nil
  get "/users/sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
  get "/users/sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => :users_sign_in
  get "/users/sign_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
  get "/users/sign_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :users_sign_out
  post "/users/sign_in" => "sessions#create", :as => :user_session
  post "/users/sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => nil

  #registrations
  get "/users/sign_up" => "registrations#new", :as => :users_sign_up
  get "/users/sign_up" => "registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
  get "/users/edit" => "registrations#edit", :as => :users_edit
  get "/users/edit" => "registrations#edit", :as => :edit_user_registrations
  get "/users/cancel" => "registrations#cancel", :as => :cancel_user_registration
  post "/users/" => "registrations#create", :as => :user_registration
  put "/users" => "registrations#update"
  delete "/users" => "registrations#destroy"

  #passwords
  get "/users/password/new" => "passwords#new", :as => :users_password_new
  get "/users/password/new" => "passwords#new", :as => :new_user_password
  get "/users/password/edit" => "passwords#edit", :as => :edit_user_password
  post "/users/password" => "passwords#create"
  put "/users/password" => "passwords#update"
end



devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations', :passwords => 'passwords', :confirmations => 'confirmations', :unlocks => 'unlocks' }, :skip => [:sessions, :unlocks]
as :admin do
  #sessions
  get "/admins/sign_in" => "sessions#new"
  get "/admins/sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => :admins_sign_in
  get "/admins/sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => :new_admin_session
  get "/admins/sign_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_admin_session
  get "/admins/sign_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :admins_sign_out
  post "/admins/sign_in" => "sessions#new"
  post "/admins/sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => :admin_session

  #unlocks
  get "/admins/unlock" => "unlocks#show"
  get "/admins/unlock/new" => "unlocks#new", :as => :admins_unlock_new
  get "/admins/unlock/new" => "unlocks#new", :as => :new_admin_unlock
  post "/admins/unlock" => "unlocks#create", :as => :admin_unlock
end
```

end

## rake routes

```
                         GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
           users_sign_in GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
          users_sign_out GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
                         POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
           users_sign_up GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"new"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"new"}
              users_edit GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"edit"}
 edit_user_registrations GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"edit"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"cancel"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"create"}
                   users PUT    /users(.:format)                       {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"update"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"registrations", :action=>"destroy"}
      users_password_new GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"passwords", :action=>"new"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"passwords", :action=>"new"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"passwords", :action=>"edit"}
          users_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"passwords", :action=>"create"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"passwords", :action=>"update"}
          admins_sign_in GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
          admins_sign_in GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
       new_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
   destroy_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_out(.:format)             {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
         admins_sign_out GET    /admins/sign_out(.:format)             {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
                         POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
           admin_session POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)              {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
           admins_unlock GET    /admins/unlock(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"unlocks", :action=>"show"}
       admins_unlock_new GET    /admins/unlock/new(.:format)           {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"unlocks", :action=>"new"}
        new_admin_unlock GET    /admins/unlock/new(.:format)           {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"unlocks", :action=>"new"}
            admin_unlock POST   /admins/unlock(.:format)               {:protocol=>"https", :host=>"secure.website.com", :controller=>"unlocks", :action=>"create"}
```

I am almost positive it has to do with my cookies, anyone have 2 cents?

I can post more app code or console code if need be. I hope this has been a help to anyone setting up customized Devise and anyone incorporating SSL into their rails3 app using Devise and SSLRequirement.

Hopefully we can get a complete write-up for a solid example for everyone. Thanks and let me know if you have any questions about how I set up custom devise controllers/views/etc...